# Android background activity disappears when coming back to the app

Tags: android, android-activity, background, dialog

I have activity `A` and `B` both visible on screen at the same time.

`A` is a full screen activity, and `B` is a smaller dialog activity. `B` (the dialog) is on top of `A` and is currently active. `A` is visible below, but is paused.

There's a button in the `B` dialog which when clicked, takes the user out of the application with a share `Intent`, for example to Gmail. After going back to the application, the background full screen activity `A` is black and only the dialog activity is visible.

Is there a way to signal activity `A` to redraw itself when coming back into the application, without closing activity `B` (the dialog)?

Below is a screenshot of the screen before going out of the app. You can see both activities one over the other.

[image: Before leaving the app]

Below is a screenshot of the screen after returning back to the app. You can see that the background activity is missing, while the dialog activity is still visible and OK.

[image: After coming back]

I wonder if there's a way to signal the background activity to redraw itself without closing the dialog activity (startActivity won't do the trick, as the background activity would become foreground).

The definition of the background activity in AndroidManifest.xml is:

```
        <activity
            android:name="com.mypackage.thegame.GameActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:launchMode="singleTask"
            />
```

--- UPDATE ---

I think I know the reason for this, but still haven't succeeded with a workaround.

Activity `A` is not a standard activity built from XML definition. It is a pure `SurfaceView` activity. It creates a `SurfaceView` and directly calls `setContent(mySurfaceView)`. The surface view starts a thread `onResume` and kills it `onPause`. That's why when going back to the application the view doesn't starts drawing, as the `onResume` is not called.

However, I found that the `onStart` method is called and I placed code inside it to render just one frame of the current state in a separate thread (also tried in the thread where it's called). But it seems that the surface view cannot get the `holder` and canvas on which to draw... I'll continue investigating and post more details if discovered.

Comment: This makes no sense. Does this occur on all devices?

Comment: Actually, if Android kills off your app's OS process when it launches GMail, upon returning from GMail to your app, Android will create a new OS process and reinstantiate the `Activity` that is on the top of the stack (in this case the Dialog-themed `Activity`). That might be what you are seeing. To check that, add logging to `onCreate()`, `onPause()` and `onResume()` in both activities to see what is happening.

Comment: It happens on all devices and I think I know what is the reason, but I still haven't succeeded with a workaround. I'll write an update above in the question.

Comment: This is not a normal usage of activities. I think you should create 2 different fragments hosted by 1 activity thus you can manage 2 screens easily.

Comment: I may try this approach with fragments if I can't make it otherwise, thank you for the idea. But why you think this usage of activities is not OK? It seems fine to have 2 overlapping activities, one of which is smaller - it may look like a dialog or it may be just another overlay component. The code is legacy and its development has started before the introduction of fragments and having two activities like that doesn't seem incorrect conceptually. Also the Android Toolkit allows it, but it seems that I don't know how to handle the situation properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally did it. I'll describe my workaround in case someone happens to have the same issue.

Lifecycle methods of the background activity `A` are as follows:

```
App Launch

-> onCreate
-> onStart
-> onResume (drawing thread is started)

Dialog Activity B Launches

-> onPause (drawing thread is killed)

Leave App

---

Come back to App

-> onStart (nothing happens, drawing thread does not exist)
```

The only place where `A` may redraw itself is the `onStart` method. There I check if we're coming from Share and if so, I render just a single frame. The code in activity `A` looks something like this:

```java
class MyActivity {
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        if (afterShare) {
            surfaceView.renderSingleFrame();
        }
    }
}
```

The hacky thing is that I loop and try to get the surface holder and canvas. If not successful, sleep for 50ms and try again a few times. It usually succeeds to take the holder on the second iteration.

The code to render a single frame is something like this:

```java
public void renderSingleFrame() {
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            int retry = 0;
            while(retry < 5) {
                if (!holder.getSurface().isValid()) {
                    retry++;  
                    try { Thread.sleep(50); } catch (InterruptedException e) {}  
                    continue;               
                }

                Canvas canvas = null;  

                try {  
                    canvas = holder.lockCanvas();  
                    if (canvas != null) {
                        this.drawFrame(canvas, 0); // canvas, deltaTime
                    }
                }  
                catch(Exception e) {}  
                finally {  
                    if (canvas != null && holder.getSurface().isValid()) {  
                        holder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas);  
                    } 
                }

                break;
            }
        }
    };

    Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
    thread.start();
}
```